# password authentication failed for user "postgres" in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, vps

I'm running a postgres image on VPS Ubuntu using docker compose.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: '3'

name: my-app
services:
  app-db:
    image: postgres:16.1
    container_name: app-db-dev
    env_file:
      - ./envs/app-db.dev.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - app-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  app-db-data:
```

**./envs/app-db.dev.env**:

```
POSTGRES_DB=my_db
POSTGRES_USER=my_db_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty1234
```

After starting the container (`docker compose up`) I see the following output:

```
app-db-dev  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
app-db-dev  | This user must also own the server process.
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
app-db-dev  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
app-db-dev  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | Data page checksums are disabled.
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
app-db-dev  | creating subdirectories ... ok
app-db-dev  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
app-db-dev  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
app-db-dev  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
app-db-dev  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
app-db-dev  | creating configuration files ... ok
app-db-dev  | running bootstrap script ... ok
app-db-dev  | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
app-db-dev  | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
app-db-dev  | initdb: hint: You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
app-db-dev  | syncing data to disk ... ok
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | waiting for server to start....2024-01-25 12:10:46.454 UTC [46] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.460 UTC [46] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.470 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-25 12:10:45 UTC
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.479 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app-db-dev  |  done
app-db-dev  | server started
app-db-dev  | CREATE DATABASE
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.786 UTC [46] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
app-db-dev  | waiting for server to shut down....2024-01-25 12:10:46.791 UTC [46] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.803 UTC [46] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 52) exited with exit code 1
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.804 UTC [47] LOG:  shutting down
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.808 UTC [47] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.953 UTC [47] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 923 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.037 s, sync=0.076 s, total=0.149 s; sync files=301, longest=0.017 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4257 kB, estimate=4257 kB; lsn=0/1913070, redo lsn=0/1913070
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:46.966 UTC [46] LOG:  database system is shut down
app-db-dev  |  done
app-db-dev  | server stopped
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
app-db-dev  | 
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.045 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.045 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.045 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.053 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.072 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-01-25 12:10:46 UTC
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.083 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

After a few seconds I start getting endless errors:

```
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.939 UTC [66] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
app-db-dev  | 2024-01-25 12:10:47.939 UTC [66] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
app-db-dev  |   Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 128: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

I will be glad for any help.

None of the solutions on the Internet helped me. When changing the port in docker-compose.yml from "5432:5432" to "**5433**:5432" the error does not appear. The command lsof -i :5432 does not return anything. With this error, I can still connect from pgAdmin using the user my_db_user. I also successfully connect in the container `docker exec -it app-db-dev psql -U my_db_user -d my_db`, but the error is still stored in the logs.

Comment: Those error messages mean something is attempting to connect to postgres with the wrong credentials. The fact that changing the published port makes the errors go away suggests that something on your host or elsewhere on the network is initiating those connections.

Comment: First ensure no other services are running on port 5432 on your host. If necessary, continue using the alternate port "5433:5432" if it resolves the conflict. Also, investigate any external applications that might be trying to connect to PostgreSQL and adjust their configurations accordingly.

Comment: @larsks, What are some ways to check that something is trying to connect?

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com I checked the command lsof -i:5432

Comment: The issue might come from the volume which contains old user and role data. Try removing the `volume` attribute of your docker-compose (i.e run your docker-compose without volumes), still with the 5432 port.

Comment: @ABWassim I removed volumes from docker compose and the error still persists. I also see some kind of anonymous volume that is being created.

Comment: It isn't clear where you ran `lsof -i:5432` or in which of the situations you describe you ran it.  But since the connection attempts fail immediately, there is no reason to think you should see anything useful from an instantaneous snap shot.

Comment: @jjanes I run a container and check on my host whether port 5432 might be occupied by something else to create conflicts - lsof -i:5432 returns nothing.

Comment: If you let any random person from the internet connect to your database, then they will try to do so.  If you use good passwords, they will fail, but they will still try.  Either configure your firewall to block it, or just ignore the log file entries.

Comment: @Yaroslav-BV Ok so can you try again with `docker-compose down --volumes` and `docker-compose up`, still on port `5432` ? Also make sure that both `volumes` section in the `docker-compose.yaml` are deleted.